# Tensorflow Warning every time I import it - 'cudart64_101.dll not found'. Is there a way to get rid of only this warning?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
2021-01-26 17:13:35.314383: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2021-01-26 17:13:35.321533: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

The execution of the code tends to pause for a while when this occurs. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Install/compile a version of TensorFlow without CUDA support.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with Tensorflow 2.0, setting `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` should still work

You can disable all logs using os.environ:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf
```

Here,

```
0 = all messages are logged (default behavior)
1 = INFO messages are not printed
2 = INFO and WARNING messages are not printed
3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not printed
```

(The above is tested on TensorFlow 0.12 and 1.0)

Comment: Works, but does this silence all debugging logs?